# Display username on every webpage after login in Angular

Tags: angularjs, authentication

I'm using Satellizer for authentication in my Angular app and have pretty much everything working... except that I can't seem to figure out how to display the username  (or email) after successful login in the navbar.

My login controller looks like this

```
$scope.login = function() {
   $auth.login($scope.user).then(function(response) {
      $scope.user = JSON.stringify(response.data.user);
      localStorage.setItem('user', user);
      $scope.user = response.data;
      $rootScope.authenticated = true;
      $rootScope.currentUser = response.data.user;
      // redirect user here after successful login
      $state.go('home');
   }
}
```

I have this in my $states (using UI Router) for global access

```
.run(function ($rootScope, $auth, $state) {
    $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function (event, toState, fromState) {
        if (toState.loginRequired && !$auth.isAuthenticated()) {
        //if ($auth.isAuthenticated()) {
            $rootScope.currentUser = JSON.parse($state, localStorage.currentUser);
        //$rootScope.currentUser = JSON.stringify($state, localStorage.currentUser);
            $state.go('/login');
            event.preventDefault();
        };
    });
  });
```

And then this in my navbar controller

```
.controller('NavbarCtrl', function($scope, $rootScope, $window, $auth) {
    $scope.isAuthenticated = function() {
      return $auth.isAuthenticated();
      $scope.user.email = $localStorage.currentUser.email;
    }
}
```

I'm not getting any errors in the console, so I'm not sure exactly where I'm going wrong...?

currentUser is undefined in the localStorage, I thought I was setting that in my login controller code above...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you store the `user` object after login in `localStorage.user`, then you read `currentUser` in `NavbarCtrl` with

```
$localStorage.currentUser.email;
```

You should use the same property `user`, i.e

```
$scope.user.email = localStorage.user.email;
```

But then, why do you need this in local storage? 
since you put the `currentUser` in the `$rootScope`, you should be able to directly use it in your navbar, e.g.

```
<span>{{currentUser.email}}</span>
```

Comment: thank you, was stuck on a couple of things... still learning authentication with JWT